# convert svg files to Bitmap using Direct2D in MFC

Tags: c++, svg, mfc, directx, direct2d

I want to convert svg files to Bitmap.I read that Direct2D support loading and using svg files. How to use it in MFC?

I tried code from [Direct2D SVG image rendering sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/d2dsvgimage/). But could not render/draw on MFC window.

I want to use converted Bitmaps for various MFC Control widgets.

Comment: A [`SwapChainPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel) is a XAML control, that can be linked into a XAML visual tree. It doesn't render its contents and needs to be sourced from a DirectX swap chain. If you aren't using a XAML UI you can skip the `SwapChainPanel` and immediately [create a swap chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-create-swap-chain).

Comment: Is it possible to convert svg to Bitmap directly without Swapchain?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you can use ID2D1Factory::CreateDCRenderTarget https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1factory-createdcrendertarget to render on an HDC or use ID2D1Factory::CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget to create a WIC bitmap that you can save as a file (or copy into a GDI/GDI+ bitmap); If you specify a bit more what you want to do with the svg, I can provide a sample.

Comment: If you create a render target that's backed by a bitmap, you can request the `ID2D1DeviceContext5` interface and call [`ID2D1DeviceContext5::DrawSvgDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_3/nf-d2d1_3-id2d1devicecontext5-drawsvgdocument) to turn the vector graphics into raster graphics for a particular set of raster properties. I believe that Direct2D is the only system component that supports SVGs.

Comment: @SimonMourier I want to convert svg to Bitmap so that I can use them for CButton, CTreeCtrl and many other. It would very helpful if you could share some code snippets or basic examples.

Comment: @IInspectable  Yes you are right Direct2D is the only system to support SVG. I could succesfully implement ID2D1DeviceContext5::CreateSvgDocument() and read attributes & elements based on previous suggestions. But I am unable not Draw it & show on the screen. Could you please help me with it

Comment: There are many "bitmaps" types in the Windows world, what exactly is a "Bitmap" in your context.

Comment: @SimonMourier  I would like to convert it to CBitmap

Comment: @SimonMourier Took a bit of effort, but the question is now eligible to receive answers again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a console app sample that uses Direct2D to create an MFC [CBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbitmap-class) from an SVG file with support for transparency. Since the CBitmap is GDI/HDC based, I've used the [ID2D1DCRenderTarget interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1dcrendertarget) .

Note: error checkings are not done, I just return the HRESULT values:

```
#define _AFXDLL // depends on your compilation options
#include <WinSock2.h> // MFC...
#include <windows.h>
#include <afxwin.h> // CBitmap
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h> // CComPtr
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1_3.h> // ID2D1DeviceContext5

#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")

void BuildSvgAsCBitmap(int width, int height)
{
    // initialize Direct2D
    D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options = { D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION }; // remove this in release
    CComPtr<ID2D1Factory> factory;
    auto hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, IID_ID2D1Factory, &options, (void**)&factory);

    // create an in-memory bitmap
    BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo = {};
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmapInfo.bmiHeader);
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    CBitmap bitmap;
    void* bits = 0;
    bitmap.Attach(CreateDIBSection(nullptr, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &bits, nullptr, 0));

    // create a DC render target
    CComPtr<ID2D1DCRenderTarget> target;
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = {};
    props.pixelFormat.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    props.pixelFormat.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;
    hr = factory->CreateDCRenderTarget(&props, &target);

    // create a DC, select bitmap and bind DC
    CDC cdc;
    cdc.CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr);
    auto old = cdc.SelectObject(bitmap);
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, width, height };
    hr = target->BindDC(cdc.GetSafeHdc(), &rc);

    // this requires Windows 10 1703
    CComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext5> dc;
    hr = target->QueryInterface(&dc);

    // open a stream from the .SVG file
    CComPtr<IStream> svgStream;
    hr = SHCreateStreamOnFileW(L"c:\\mypath\\myfile.svg", 0, &svgStream);

    // open the SVG as a document
    CComPtr<ID2D1SvgDocument> svg;
    D2D1_SIZE_F size = { (float)width, (float)height };
    hr = dc->CreateSvgDocument(svgStream, size, &svg);

    // draw it on the render target
    target->BeginDraw();
    dc->DrawSvgDocument(svg);
    hr = target->EndDraw();

    // TODO
    // do something with the CBitmap
    // TODO

    // cleanup, etc.
    cdc.SelectObject(old);
}

int main()
{
    BuildSvgAsCBitmap(200, 200);
    return 0;
}
```

There's a more complete sample here https://gist.github.com/smourier/5b770d32043121d477a8079ef6be0995 that also demonstrates how to save the svg as a png with transparency using WIC.

Comment: @iinspectable - you don't need CoInitialize in this sample.

Comment: Are you sure? Direct2D doesn't require the COM infrastructure, but what about the `IStream` that gets created? Feel free to roll back the edit if COM isn't strictly required.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, I've tested it :-) Wic (in my link) does require it.

Comment: How can we Resize it? I tried with other svg files with different sizes, but there is loss of information. If you provide the correct Box size of svg then only complete Bitmap is visible.

Comment: @latosvarun - resize what? an SVG is vector-based (you can use any viewport size in CreateSvgDocument) so you can use the width & height you want like demonstrated in my code

Comment: @SimonMourier Sorry, i think i have bad svg files. But Resize with 'drawing.svg' example file works perfectly fine 

Comment: I'm not confident that you can *"test it"*, though ([Why does `CoCreateInstance` work even though my thread never called CoInitialize? The curse of the implicit MTA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130419-00/?p=4613)).

Comment: @IInspectable - well, I did test it, and no, there's no implicit CoInitialize as nothing here needs it, and there's no CoCreateInstance involved. Put CoInitialize(Ex) after BuildSvgAsCBitmap and you'll see it returns S_OK, not S_FALSE nor RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE